# NVARCHAR converted to an out of range datetime value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written a program that obtains data from our service provider on Driving Licences.

This is pumped out to a Windows Form / GUI for easy of reading by the advisor.

I have 2 SQL Servers, one based in one office SQL Server 2012 and one in another office 2008. While I agree this is not ideal both offices act independently. The software returns the data and inputs it into a SQL table for auditing purposes.

To do this it converts a DataTable in VB.NET to SQL and it uses a stored procedure and a 'User Defined Table Type' to get this into SQL.

I am based in the office that has the SQL 2008 Server, the software works perfectly fine, if I deploy the software to the other offices DOMAIN (Trusted) a input it INTO our SQL it works fine.

However if I try to input the data into their SQL Server I get:

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The data for table-valued parameter "@Endorsements" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. The statement has been terminated.
```

I have changed the Language Settings for both SQL Server and they are set to 'British English' the regional settings are also the same.

Below is the User defined datatype and the Stored Procedure. Can someone please explain to me why this is occurring, BOTH SP's and UDT's are exactly the same on both servers.

I have also added the Create Table code of the table I am trying to insert the data into.

**SP**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MyL_InsertEndorsements]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Endorsements [dbo].[MyL_EndorsementDetails] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO dbo.MyL_Audit_Endorsements
        ( Code ,
          [Offence Date] ,
          [Conviction Date] ,
          Fine ,
          Points ,
          Disqualification ,
          [Disqualification Period] ,
          [Disqual Start Date] ,
          [Disqual End Date] ,
          [Custodial Period] ,
          [Rehab Spent Date] ,
          DLN ,
          RequestDT
        )
SELECT Code ,
       [Offence Date] ,
       [Conviction Date] ,
       Fine ,
       Points ,
       Disqualification ,
       [Disqualification Period] ,
       [Disqual Start Date] ,
       [Disqual End Date] ,
       [Custodial Period] ,
       [Rehab Spent Date] ,
       DLN ,
       DATEADD(ms, -(DATEPART(ms, RequestDT)), RequestDT) FROM @Endorsements
END
```

**UDT**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyL_EndorsementDetails] AS TABLE(
[Code] [VARCHAR](5) NULL,
[Offence Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
[Conviction Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
[Fine] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Points] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Disqualification] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Disqualification Period] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
[Disqual Start Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Disqual End Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Custodial Period] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Rehab Spent Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[DLN] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[RequestDT] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

**CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyL_Audit_Endorsements](
[Code] [VARCHAR](5) NULL,
[Offence Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
[Conviction Date] [DATETIME] NULL,
[Fine] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Points] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Disqualification] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
[Disqualification Period] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
[Disqual Start Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Disqual End Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Custodial Period] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[Rehab Spent Date] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[DLN] [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
[RequestDT] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Code Being Executed in .NET**

```
Public Shared Sub DataTableToSQL(ByVal DataTable As DataTable, ByVal SPName As String)

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ObtainSQLConn(Audit.Domain))
        'SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()

        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SPName, cn)

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            If SPName = "usp_MyL_InsertEndorsements" Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Endorsements", DataTable)
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenceDets", DataTable)
            End If

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

**VB.NET Created DataTable**

```
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Code", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Offence Date", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Conviction Date", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Fine", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Points", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Disqualification?", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Disqualification Period", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Disqual Start Date", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Disqual End Date", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Custodial Period", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Rehab Spent Date", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DLN", GetType(String)))
        Results.EndorsementsTbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RequestDT", GetType(Date)))
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Because you have defined "dates" in your user defined table type as varchar(30). Then when you insert that into your table it has do convert that to the proper datatype and you obviously have some values that are invalid. This is why you should NEVER store datetime information in varchar columns.

Comment: @SeanLange - Understood in terms of practice, but why does it work fine on one server but not the other? Surely if its a VARCHAR it shouldn't matter what server it is on as its not bound to Regional/Language settings it is merely text?

Comment: Maybe it is when you populate the table variable? When do you get the error? You didn't post the code that is being executed.

Comment: @SeanLange Have added this for you, the dates that are in the DataTable are dd/mm/yyyy format, this is because of how they are received from the service

Comment: OK. So where in this code do you get the error? What are the datatypes in your datatable? I suspect there is some bad data somewhere but it is hard to say.

Comment: @SeanLange have added that DT Create in, I have to use 'String' rather than date again because of how the data comes down from the feed.

Comment: Why do you **have** to use it as string? Incorrect format? maybe start there and parsing it correctly from the feed to datetime before inserting.

Comment: OK I removed all date fields, and I change my Offence Date in the table i insert into to a VARCHAR, I then have changed the UDT and SP to insert as VARCHAR's and this has worked correctly.

So my error is in converting '17/03/2014' as a VARCHAR to a DATETIME.

Comment: @mxix Yes I have to use String as an incorrect format.

Comment: I have been informed by a pal of mine that due to the difference between SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012 converting 'dd/MM/yyyy' is a bit of mucking around, so this could be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You should have the datatype in your data table be a datetime column. That will eliminate the problem on the sql side. You may have some challenges in your dot net code but that shouldn't be a big deal to overcome. Yet another example of why using the proper datatypes is so important. It isn't just a sql thing.